# Re .next() method of Scanner : What happens after last valid token read?

Tags: java, nosuchelementexception

[The docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) say that `NoSuchElementException` is thrown when it tries to read past the last valid token . Keeping that in mind, if someone writes something like this :

```
while(scanner.next() !=null){
    // read string into your variable
}
```

where they assume that null will be returned as opposed to `NoSuchElementException` being thrown after reading past the last valid token ,  ( and so they don't keep any `try-catch` block ) will they be correct in doing so ?

**EDIT:** it turns out that i *can* use .hasNext() . Problem solved.

Comment: and what happens when you try this? when you throw a bunch of test cases at this?

Comment: When i tried this , i get `Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException` at the cmd. I originally had a try-catch() block , but someone suggested that its not needed , and can be solved simply by the above method.

Comment: @SomjitNag So you know from both the docs and from experience that your code snippet is wrong. Why did you still ask this question, then?

Comment: why can't you use `hasNext()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is absolutely non-sensical to forbid using the hasNext() method.

That said, while breaking the "rules" of your question, you should be using the following idiom:

```
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String s = scanner.next();
    // do stuff...
}
```

If your situation is that you are curious, then sure, a NoSuchElementException will be thrown when there are no more tokens to be read. The only way to "check" this is a try-catch block. It will **not** return null in the case of an exception. Your program will simply die, provided you don't handle the exception...